# How can you remove object from NSCache?

Tags: objective-c

I can see how do you save objects, and get objects, but i couldn't find how can i remove objects ?
(i know the remove policy but i want to remove things by my own)

add:

```
 [self.myCache setObject:image forKey:number];
```

get:

```
[self.myCache objectForKey:number];
```

remove ?

Comment: What is wrong with `removeObjectForKey:` or `removeAllObjects` ?

Comment: oh .. i am sorry ! somehow Xcode was giving me error for that, but it was for something else. it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.myCache removeObjectForKey:number];
```

([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCache/removeObjectForKey%3a))